# display inline-block not working on col-xs-6 bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm working on a non-responsive site where i want to have an image and text next to eachother in a col-xs-6. Only when i use display:inline-block it's not working.

I thought using li would make it work, but it doesn't. What happens in that col-xs-6 that is blocking the inline-block? Hopefully this is enough info to help me get the solution.

You can find my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/robin2609/h0hoss1o/2/

This is my code:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 item-background">             
          <div class="row" style="  border:1px solid red; float:none; display:inline-block;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">              
                <h2 class="items">Test</h2>             
                <ul>
                    <li style="display:inline-block;  border:1px solid red;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
                    </li>
                    <li style="display:inline-block;  border:1px solid red;">
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor                 incididunt uLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt u
                    </li>
                </ul>                                       
            </div>          
            <div class="col-xs-6">              
                <h2 class="items">Test</h2>             
                <ul>
                    <li style="display:inline-block;  border:1px solid red;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
                    </li>
                    <li style="display:inline-block;  border:1px solid red;">
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor                 incididunt uLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt u
                    </li>
                </ul>                                       
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why use bootstrap if you are making no-responsive webpage?

Comment: @Justinas twitter bootstrap hasn't been created for responsive webpages only...

Comment: It might be a possibility in the feature, so i'm making it easier for myself in the future.

Comment: have a look at my answer, is that what you're looking for...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `col-xs-XX` instead of `display:inline` for each element, that way they'll be placed next to each other. Make sure that each row’s `col-xs-XX` adds up to a total of 12.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 item-background">
    <div class="row" style="  border:1px solid red; float:none; display:inline-block;">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2 class="items">Test</h2> 
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt uLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt u</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2 class="items">Test</h2> 
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="border:1px solid red;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt uLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt u</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h0hoss1o/8/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is workin now, but i can't figure out why both col-xs-3's only use col-xs-6 for 50%. See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/robin2609/h0hoss1o/6/

Comment: Use `col-xs-6` instead of `col-xs-3`.

Comment: haha ofcourse when nesting i always have to count to 12 in total.
I feel so dumb now for asking that question :) Thank you all for your input. It's working now!